# Having a table,an iframe,and a table displayed side by side

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, line-breaks

I'm trying to display a table, an iframe, and a table side by side. There are no breaks or anything in between. I'd like all three centered preferably.

This makes no sense. There is plenty of room for them all to be displayed on the same "line" as my screen display is large enough.

Please help.

Code shown below:

```html
<center>




<table border="0">
<tr id="hidethis" style="display:none;">
<td><iframe src="menu.html"height=450 width=400 frameborder=0 name = "list" style =""></></iframe></td>
</tr>
<tr id="hidethisalso" style="display:none;">
<td>Enter code for song to play</td>
</tr>
</table>





<iframe height=450 width=450 frameborder=0 name = "cake" style =""></></iframe>



<table border="0">
<tr id="hidethistoo" style="display:none;">
<td><iframe src="menu.html"height=450 width=400 frameborder=0 name = "list" style =""></></iframe></td>
</tr>
<tr id="hidethisaswell" style="display:none;">
<td>Enter code for song to delete</td>
</tr>
</table>

</center>
```

Comment: you could try wrapping each table in it's own div that has style `display:inline-block`

Comment: Do you know of a way using only Javascript and HTML -- not using CSS. Thanks anyway for your help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you have inline css, why can't the solution do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table in `<div style="inline-block">...</div>`

this will make the table behave for you

```html
<center>
<!-- wrap the table in an inline-block to make it behave -->
<div style="display:inline-block">
<table border="0">
<tr id="hidethis" style="display:;">
<td><iframe src="menu.html"height=450 width=400 frameborder=0 name = "list" style =""></></iframe></td>
</tr>
<tr id="hidethisalso" style="display:none;">
<td>Enter code for song to play</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<iframe height=450 width=450 frameborder=0 name = "cake" style =""></></iframe>
<!-- wrap the table in an inline-block to make it behave -->
<div style="display:inline-block">
<table border="0">
<tr id="hidethistoo" style="display:;">
<td><iframe src="menu.html"height=450 width=400 frameborder=0 name = "list" style =""></></iframe></td>
</tr>
<tr id="hidethisaswell" style="display:none;">
<td>Enter code for song to delete</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</center>
```